# Is there ellipsis after the conjunction?

Tags: conjunctions

> “No, Harry, he has not. He is still out there somewhere, perhaps
>   looking for another body to share… not being truly alive, he cannot be
>   killed. He left Quirrell to die; he shows just as little mercy to his
>   followers **as** his enemies. Nevertheless, Harry, while you may only
>   have delayed his return to power, it will merely take someone else who
>   is prepared to fight what seems a losing battle next time — and if he
>   is delayed again, and again, why, he may never return to power.”
>   (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

Is there ellipsis after as, *he shows little mercy to*?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. "Is there an ellipsis after the word 'as'? or "Is there an ellipsis after the phrase 'he shows little mercy to'? Either way, I don't think it matters. I wouldn't use an ellipsis in either place. Please explain your reasoning further.

Comment: @KansasTeacher I think Listenever means ellipsis as in an omitted word. (Listenever, am I interpreting your question correctly?) Does the sentence mean “he shows little mercy to his followers, and he shows equally little mercy to his enemies”? I would indeed expect “as little mercy to his followers as **to** his enemies” in that case. As it is, I parse the sentence as “he shows just as little mercy to his enemies as his enemies show merci to his enemies”, which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is, but not the one you suggest.

Let's start off by making it clear what we're talking about. This is an “incomplete construction”.

> From [nonfictionwritingcoach.org](http://www.nonfictionwritingcoach.org/blog.htm?post=649341):
>   ***Incomplete Constructions**
> Some sentences include incomplete constructions, in which some words are implied but not stated explicitly. Common incomplete constructions include phrases with “more/less than,” “as many/few as,” or “as much/little as.”*

The implied words (which you've correctly, though confusingly referred to as an [ellipsis](http://www.scrigroup.com/limba/engleza/99/Leaving-out-words-ellipsis25885.php)) would be:

> *...he shows just as little mercy to his followers as* **[he does to]** *his enemies.*

That is yet *another* ellipsis of a different kind, as I've used “does [show]” to avoid repeating “shows”.